# Is there a fail over mechanism with NLog?

Tags: c#, logging, nlog, failover

I am using NLog for DB logging. If the DB is down then I only need it to log to a file. Is there a way to do this?

I don't want to record log entries log in both a file and the DB. If the DB target fails to log (if DB is down) only then do I have to log to the file. Is there any fail over or fallback feature with Nlog?

Comment: I guess most Logging Frameworks handle (internal) exceptions like these and (possibly) consuming app does not have an idea about it (unless you can subscribe to some exposed event which may be triggered when DB connection breaks). But nothing stops you from writing your own Appender. There will be an Interface/BaseClass that you can extend.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a way. It's called a `FallbackGroup`.

Documentation can be found here: https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/FallbackGroup-target

Here is an example taken blatantly and ashamedly from the documentation:

```xml
<target xsi:type="FallbackGroup" 
        name="mail"
        returnToFirstOnSuccess="true">
    <target xsi:type="Mail"
            name="mailserver1"
            subject="Layout"
            to="Layout"
            from="Layout"
            smtpServer="mx1.example.com" 
            smtpPort="Integer"
            layout="Layout" />
    <target xsi:type="Mail"
            name="mailserver2" 
            subject="Layout"
            to="Layout"
            from="Layout"
            smtpServer="mx2.example.com" 
            smtpPort="Integer"
            layout="Layout" />
</target>
<rules>
  <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="mail" />
</rules>
```

It'll try another mail server if the first fails. It'll also return to the first target if it's successful.

I never used it in production, maybe the other options in the documentation can help you fine tune it to your problem.