# NLog fallover : Log scaling

Tags: c#, logging, nlog

I'm fairly sure that what I want exists, but I just don't know what to look for.

What I want to implement is a way for NLog to log to a different target, if the initial attempt failed. For instance; I want to log all Info-level to my Db. However, if that logging failed, I want to send out an email, if that fails, log to file.

Is my thought process on the architecture wrong? Is there a better way of doing this, or is there already a way of doing this?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49788880/is-there-a-fail-over-mechanism-with-nlog ? (Hopefully it will not become a broken link)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a fail over mechanism with NLog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49788880/is-there-a-fail-over-mechanism-with-nlog)